# R - conditional pattern matching using grepl

Tags: r, dataframe, text, pattern-matching, grepl

I have two data frames, like so:

```
name <- c("joe", "kim", "kerry", "david")
name2 <- c("kim", "david", "joe", "kerry")
school <- c("cambridge", "south carolina", "vermont binghamton", "delaware")
school2 <- c("south carolina", "delaware", "cambridge magdalene", "vermont")

df1 <- data.frame(name, school)
df2 <- data.frame(name2, school2)
```

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Search `df2$name2` for a match in `df1$name`.
2. If a match is found, compare `df2$school2` to `df1$school` from the matching row.
3. If no match is found for `df2$school2` in  `df1$school`, return FALSE in column `df2$perfect.match`

So for example, since "joe" in `df2` matches "joe" in `df1`,  there's a match.  However, since the values for "school" in both aren't the same, the would be a column in `df2` with a value of FALSE in the third row. Same for 4th row in `df2`.

I have tried using grep and grepl.  I figure grepl would be best, since it returns a logical value.  What I tried was:

```
df2$perfect.match <- ifelse(grepl(paste(df2$name2, collapse = "|"), 
df1$name, fixed = F) & grepl(paste(df2$school2, collapse = "|"), df1$school, fixed = F), "", "FALSE")
```

however, all I get is this:

```
  name2             school2 perfect.match
1   kim      south carolina         FALSE
2 david            delaware              
3   joe cambridge magdalene              
4 kerry             vermont
```

When my desired result is:

```
  df2

  name2             school2 perfect.match
1   kim      south carolina         
2 david            delaware              
3   joe cambridge magdalene         FALSE     
4 kerry             vermont         FALSE
```

If possible, something speedy would be best.  The real dataframe are quite large. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I would like to also be able to force the rows that are false to have the same value for `df2$school` as their corresponding `name` match in `df1$school` Like so:

```
  name2             school2
1   kim      south carolina
2 david            delaware
3   joe           cambridge 
4 kerry   vermont binghamton
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` and `%in%`. `grepl` wouldn't be right here since this is exact matching and not pattern matching.

```
df2$perfect_match <- df2$school2 %in% df1$school[match(df2$name2, df1$name)]
df2
#  name2             school2 perfect_match
#1   kim      south carolina          TRUE
#2 david            delaware          TRUE
#3   joe cambridge magdalene         FALSE
#4 kerry             vermont         FALSE
```

Comment: What if it were pattern matching?  Would it just be `grepl(...fixed = T)`?

Comment: @jvalenti yes in that case you could use `str_detect` from `stringr` and do `str_detect(df2$school2, as.character(df1$school[match(df2$name2, df1$name)]))` which would give you `TRUE` for `joe` as well.

Comment: what if I wanted to also return the row index of `df1` where the `FALSE` match for `df1$school` was located?

Comment: @jvalenti That would be `match(df2$name2, df1$name)[!df2$perfect_match]`

Comment: I think this only works if both df has the same number of rows because I get an error `replacement has X rows, data has Y`

Comment: hmm...not sure what might have happened. Can you update your post with related example ?

Comment: updated with desired result.  Basically I want to be able to find the rows where FALSE occur and force the values for `df`$school` to match `df2$school` if they are different.

Comment: @jvalenti in that case wouldn't that be just `df2$match <- df1$school[match(df2$name2, df1$name)]` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can just do...

```
df2$perfect.match <- paste(df2$name2, df2$school2) %in% paste(df1$name, df1$school)

df2
  name2             school2 perfect.match
1   kim      south carolina          TRUE
2 david            delaware          TRUE
3   joe cambridge magdalene         FALSE
4 kerry             vermont         FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly faster than pasting the columns together:

```
matches <- df2$name2 %in% df1$name
df2$perfect.match <- df2$school2[matches] %in% df1$school

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  v1 = {matches <- df2$name2 %in% df1$name
  df2$perfect.match <- df2$school2[matches] %in% df1$school
  },
  v2 = {df2$perfect.match <- paste(df2$name2, df2$school2) %in% paste(df1$name, df1$school)}
)
```

Comment: But this won't work if there are names in `df1` that aren't in `df2` (as the vectors will be different lengths)

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, you can do:

```r
dfX <- df1 %>%
  bind_rows(.,df2) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  distinct(school) %>%
  count(name, name = "perfect.matched") %>% 
  left_join(df2,.,by = 'name') %>%
  mutate(., perfect.matched = ifelse(perfect.matched ==1,"","FALSE"))
```

And to get the following output:

```r
> dfX
   name              school perfect.matched
1   kim      south carolina                
2 david            delaware                
3   joe cambridge magdalene           FALSE
4 kerry             vermont           FALSE
```